# App.config runtime probing with wildcard or recursive

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to load dll's via the `<probing>` element. I have a folder structure that consists of several plugin folders inside of plugins. So I am looking for a way to recursively go through all these plugins folders to find the dll's.

This is my folder structure:

- MyApplication

  - myapp.exe
- plugins

  - fooplugin

    - foo.dll
  - barplugin

    - bar.dll

This is what my App.config looks like, but it doesn't seem to catch the `plugins\*` part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="MyApplication;plugins;plugins\*;"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If I would make it like: `<probing privatePath="MyApplication;plugins;plugins\fooplugin;">` it will find foo.dll. But I am not certain which plugins will be present.

Comment: I am not familiar to this but what would be the difference between plugins; & plugins\* ?? looks same to me.

Comment: The probing doesn't go through the folders recursively, so it won't find foo.dll, because it is in a subfolder of plugins.

Comment: I don't think you can search that way.

Comment: yes, @DavidG is correct.

Comment: If you have your plugin projects all compiling to different locations, you can change so they compile to a shared plugin folder or have a post build task that copies the DLLs to a shared folder.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Why do you need to avoid that?

Comment: the fooplugin folder contains more than just a single dll. Putting everyting into a single folder will make a mess. It should be possible to add and remove plugins via windows explorer

Comment: @Marnix why don't you append the privatePath at runtime then?

Comment: Then have a post build task on the `MyApplication` project that only copies the files you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a wildcard search when using the [`probing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx) element. Instead you need to copy your DLLs into a shared folder or specify every folder where they might exist.

If your plugins are being generated by other projects you can set them to build directly to your plugin folder or preferably have a post build task in the `MyApplication` project that copies the files into your project plugins folder.

Comment: I would like to have folders inside my plugins folder. Could you show me how to append the privatePath at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do what you want by handling the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

then inside the attached event handler just call:

`Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path: assemblyPath);
 return assembly; // return resolved assembly`

The `assemblyPath` is the absolute path to the DLL your program is trying to grab, and you could get that by scanning your DLL folder at runtime and then grabbing the path that contains the missing DLL name.